PySimpleGUI App Layouts Not Resizing Properly When Changing Layouts on the Same Window"?
My app has different layouts that update visibily to hide and unhide the layouts. Hiding these layouts and showing a different one is done through event calls(button clicks). The problem is that when these layouts are changed, the window doesn't adjust itself to match the elements of the new layout. For example layout one has 3 input elements and 2 buttons but layout two has a table element, when switching to display layout two the table is smaller than the window.
Code:
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from database import *

sg.set_options(font=("Courier", 12))

#get all added records from database
records = getRecords()
print(records)

#check if inputs are empty
def checkMissingInput(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i == '':
            return True
    return False

#create window to add records
def main():
    #root/main layout
    addRecordsLayout = [
        [sg.Push(), sg.Text("Password Manager"), sg.Push()],
        [sg.Text("URL "), sg.Push(), sg.Input("www.apple.com",enable_events=True, key="input-url")],
        [sg.Text("Username/Email "), sg.Push(), sg.Input("johndoe@gmail.com",enable_events=True, key="input-username")],
        [sg.Text("Password "), sg.Push(), sg.Input("john123",enable_events=True, key="input-password")],

        [sg.Button("Add Record", enable_events=True, key="add-records", expand_x=True), 
         sg.Button("Show Records", enable_events=True, key="show-records", expand_x=True), 
         sg.Button("Clear", enable_events=True, key="clear", expand_x=True)]
    ]

    #second layout, for viewing table of records
    toprows = ["Id","Url","Username","Password"]
    showRecordsLayout = [
        [sg.Push(),sg.Text("Records"),sg.Push()],
        [sg.Push(),sg.Table(key='records-table',values=records, headings=toprows, 
                  expand_x=True,
                  expand_y=True,
                  justification="center",
                  auto_size_columns=True,
                  enable_click_events=True 
                  ),sg.Push()],
        [sg.Button("Select",key="select-records",expand_x=True,enable_events=True),
         sg.Button("Exit",key="exit-show-records",expand_x=True,enable_events=True)]
    ]

    #third layout, for viewing selected layout from table
    showSelectedRecordLayout = [
        #[sg.Text(f"Record {selectRecordId}")]
        [sg.Text("Url: ")],
        [sg.Text("Username: ")],
        [sg.Text("Password: ")],

        [sg.Button("Delete", expand_x=True, key="delete-record-button"),
         sg.Button("Return", expand_x=True, key="exit-selected-record")]
    ]

    rootLayout = [[sg.Column(addRecordsLayout, key="column-1", visible=True)],
                  [sg.Column(showRecordsLayout, key="column-2", visible=False)],
                  [sg.Column(showSelectedRecordLayout, key="column-3", visible=False)]]

    window = sg.Window("Password Manager", rootLayout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
    
        #events
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            print(event)
        
            break
        elif event == 'clear':
            window['input-url'].update('')
            window['input-username'].update('')
            window['input-password'].update('')

        elif event == 'add-records':
            inputElementValues = list(values.values()) #get list all values in input elements
            try:
                if checkMissingInput(inputElementValues) == True:
                    sg.popup("Missing input values...")
                else:
                    addDbRecord(inputElementValues[0], inputElementValues[1], inputElementValues[2]) #add list of input values to database table
                    sg.popup("Record succesfully added...")

            except ValueError:
                print("ValueError")
        
        elif event == 'show-records':
            window["column-1"].update(visible=False)
            window["column-2"].update(visible=True)
            window['records-table'].update(values=getRecords()) #update records table to display new added records based on whats in database table

        if event == 'exit-show-records':
            window["column-1"].update(visible=True)
            window["column-2"].update(visible=False)

        elif event == 'select-records':
            window["column-2"].update(visible=False)
            window["column-3"].update(visible=True)
            print(values['records-table'])
        
        elif event == 'exit-selected-record':
            window["column-2"].update(visible=True)
            window["column-3"].update(visible=False)
    window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I've tried updating the window size with every event, but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

The space for a row or a container will be kept when nothing inside it.
Two ways for it

Using help function sg.pin, like

    rootLayout = [
        [sg.pin(sg.Column(addRecordsLayout, key="column-1", visible=True))],
        [sg.pin(sg.Column(showRecordsLayout, key="column-2", visible=False))],
        [sg.pin(sg.Column(showSelectedRecordLayout, key="column-3", visible=False))],
    ]

or

Put all visible/invisile elements in same row, like

    rootLayout = [
        [sg.Column(addRecordsLayout, key="column-1", visible=True),
         sg.Column(showRecordsLayout, key="column-2", visible=False),
         sg.Column(showSelectedRecordLayout, key="column-3", visible=False)],
    ]

Remember call following statements to move your window center to the screen after you change the layout.
window.refresh()
window.move_to_center()


Thank you so much, it works much better now
